# Understanding the "Structure Theorem" for the Euclidean Traveling Salesman PTAS

Tags: approximation, traveling-salesman

I am trying to understand the "Structure Theorem" in [Arora's TSP slides](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-06-winter/Slides/steve_tsp_ptas_winter.pdf). In particular, I do not understand the image on slide 13-3 (page 68 of the PDF). The high level idea is to show that (without randomization/derandomization) there is a chance that you will get a "bad" approximation of the Euclidean TSP using the portal scheme described earlier in the slides. That is, the restriction of traveling through portals could result in a tour that is *not* a $(1 + \epsilon)\text{OPT}$ length portal respecting tour with the hopes that later this is fixed with randomization/derandomization.

I certainly see that there are $4m$ portals. I also see that $|\text{OPT}| \leq n^2(1 + \sqrt{2}) + 2n\sqrt{2}$. What is unclear to me is how the interportal distance is $\delta = \frac{n^2 + 2n}{8m}$. I would have thought that since they use a bounding box with side lengths of  $\sqrt{2}n^2$ that the inter-portal distance would be $\frac{\text{length}}{4m} = \frac{\sqrt{2}{n^2}}{4m}$. (In either case this would still dominate $n$).

I am having a hard time also understanding how "One crossing every $n \implies$ overhead per consecutive portals $\geq 2 \frac{\delta}{4} = \frac{\delta}{2}$." Looking at the red lines, it seems that "one crossing" gives two red lines at a total of 3 protals. As the interportal distance $\delta$ I would think that each crossing contributes $\delta$ worth distance for all vertices, not $\frac{\delta}{2}$.

I do not seem to understand how to calculate the values for $\delta$ and the "crossing contribution". Any guidance is appreciated.